# Padding columns of csv

Tags: bash, awk, command-line

I have a csv file which contains a large number of csv seperated lines of data. i want to find the maximum length of the line then need to print NO  in a new column

file.csv

```
1,2,3,4,
1,4,7,8,9,10,11,13
1,2,
1,1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11
abc,def,ghi,jkl
```

expected result

```
1,2,3,4,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,N0
1,4,7,8,9,10,11,13,,,,,NO
1,2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,NO
1,1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,NO
abc,def,ghi,jkl,,,,,,,,NO
```

```
cat file | cat > file.csv
echo "N0" >> file.csv
```

output obtained

```
1,2,3,4,NO
1,4,7,8,9,10,11,13,NO
1,2,NO
1,1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,NO
abc,def,ghi,jkl,NO
```

Comment: Should each row be filled with `,` or should each row have the same number of columns?

Comment: The output which you claim to get from `cat file | cat > file.csv; echo NO >> file.csv` is surprising. You must have magic versions of `cat` and `echo` which can guess your wishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read the file twice, once to get the maximum number of columns, once to print the output:

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{if(m<=NF)m=NF;next} # Runs only on first iteration
         {printf "%s",$0;for(i=0;i<=(m-NF);i++)printf ",";print "NO"}' file file

                                                      filename twice -----^
```

Output (12 columns in each row):

```
1,2,3,4,,,,,,,,NO
1,4,7,8,9,10,11,13,,,,NO
1,2,,,,,,,,,,NO
1,1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,NO
abc,def,ghi,jkl,,,,,,,,NO
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to imagine why you'd want to pad the lines with commas so here's what I think you really want which is to make every line have the same number of fields:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} NR==FNR{m=(m>NF?m:NF);next} {$(m+1)="NO"} 1' file file
1,2,3,4,,,,,,,,NO
1,4,7,8,9,10,11,13,,,,NO
1,2,,,,,,,,,,NO
1,1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,NO
abc,def,ghi,jkl,,,,,,,,NO
```

and here's what you said you want anyway:

```
$ awk '{n=length()} NR==FNR{m=(m>n?m:n);next} {p=sprintf("%*s",m-n+1,""); gsub(/ /,",",p); $0=$0 p "NO"} 1' file file
1,2,3,4,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,NO
1,4,7,8,9,10,11,13,,,,,,NO
1,2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,NO
1,1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,NO
abc,def,ghi,jkl,,,,,,,,,NO
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN{m=0}
{if(NF>m)m=NF;ar[NR]=$0;ars[NR]=NF;}
END{for(i=1;i<=NR;i++)
     {for(j=ars[i];j<m;j++){ar[i]=ar[i]","}ar[i]=ar[i]"NO";
                            print ar[i]}}' <<<'1,2,3,4,
1,4,7,8,9,10,11,13
1,2,
1,1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12
abc,def,ghi,jkl
a,b'
```

output:

```
1,2,3,4,,,,,,,,NO
1,4,7,8,9,10,11,13,,,,NO
1,2,,,,,,,,,,NO
1,1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12NO
abc,def,ghi,jkl,,,,,,,,NO
a,b,,,,,,,,,,NO
```

if lines must be have same size:

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN{m=0}
{if(length($0)>m)m=length($0);ar[NR]=$0;ars[NR]=length($0);}
END{for(i=1;i<=NR;i++)
       {for(j=ars[i];j<m;j++)
           {ar[i]=ar[i]","}ar[i]=ar[i]"NO";
                           print ar[i]}}' <<<'1,2,3,4,
1,4,7,8,9,10,11,13
1,2,
1,1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12
abc,def,ghi,jkl
a,b'
```

output:

```
1,2,3,4,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,NO
1,4,7,8,9,10,11,13,,,,,,,,NO
1,2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,NO
1,1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12NO
abc,def,ghi,jkl,,,,,,,,,,,NO
a,b,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,NO
```

if you want also comma after max length line run for loop until m+1;